# Is there a way to Hot Reload my Vue Page after changing an Environment Variable in VueJS?

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, hot-reload

I want to have different modes for my application, so I created different `.env` files to store my environment variables. Using these variables works fine, the only problem is that I have to restart the whole application when I change something inside the `.env` files.
I tried outsourcing the environment variables into a `.json` file to get it working with Hot Reload, which didn't work.

This is my `.env` file:

```
NODE_ENV=development
VUE_APP_JSON_FILE=./m.json
```

My `vue.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        VUE_APP_JSON: JSON.stringify(require(process.env.VUE_APP_JSON_FILE))
      })
    ]
  }
```

My `.json` file:

```
{
  "logo": {
    "picture": "test.jpg",
  }
}
```

Now I can call the variable inside the .json like `VUE_APP_JSON.logo.picture`.
 As I said, all this works, but changing variables in the .env file or the .json file doesn't trigger Hot Reload.
Anyone knows how to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to hot reload config files, then you should think if you are doing things correctly. Environment variables shouldn't change that frequently that you need hot-reload for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR;

No, you can't

---

from my experience you can't, and you'll never be able to. since .env files are "somewhat" cached (I don't really know what they call that) but once you've compiled your application you can never change the .env then expect a hot-reload

.env variables are statically used in the compiled code itself and not as a variable, therefor the when changing values in the .env file you didn't change anything on the code. you really need to recompile the project again to update the static data that your compiled code is using.

Example:

you have a code:

```
var Environment = process.env.APP_ENV
```

and your .env file has

```
APP_ENV=local
```

your compiled code will look like this

```
var Environment = 'local'
```

---

UPDATE..

you can't even make vue.config.js to hot-reload. when you change anything on that file you also really need to recompile.. since vue.config.js is the config for the compiler itself. webpack is the compiler and the vue.config.js is it's config.

Answer (score -1):

Run a build then go back to your dev version. It will apply the changes.